# what is the right order to stop/start kafka with zookeeper and schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have 3 kafka brokers in the cluster

kafka version - 1.0.0

each kafka machine include also : *zookeper server , schema registry*

what is the right order to stop/start the following services:

```
1. kafka 
2  zookeeper 
3  schema registry
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start the services:

1. ZooKeeper is a prerequisite for Kafka and Schema Registry so it has
   to go first.

   (Ideally, you would also want to verify that Leader election took place too with the 4-letter `stat` command.)
2. Kafka is a prerequisite for Schema Registry so it goes 2nd.
3. Schema Registry goes last.

To stop them, go in the reverse order.

1. Schema Registry
2. Kafka
3. ZooKeeper

#### References

- [Using Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/using.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer says, it goes like;

1. Zookeeper
2. Kafka
3. Schema Registry
4. +Kafka Connect

If you are using Kafka Connect, like me, you should start it after you've started both Zookeeper and Kafka. I don't think the order between Schema Registry and Kafka Connect matters but I do start Kafka Connect last and haven't faced any problem so far.